# Type Parameter Constraints - no generics (or nearest offer!)

Tags: c#, parameters, constraints

I am thinking what I want to do is impossible but thought I would ask anyway.  I am thinking of implementing some kind of custom conversion between different metric measurements - such as converting inches to metres and other units.

I am thinking base class called Unit as follows.  NOTE:  I have not put in any fields to hold the number of units eg 2 metres, 5 inches and so on:

```
public abstract class Unit {
    protected string _name;
    public Unit(string name)
    {
        _name = name;
    }
}
```

Then subclasses of Unit for Metre and Inch:

```
public class Metre : Unit {
    public Metre() : base("Metre")
    {
    }
}

public class Inch : Unit {
    public Metre() : base("Inch")
    {
    }
}
```

I would like to have a class that could handle conversion of these units between one another.  Something like:

```
public static class UnitConvertor
{
    public Unit Convert(Unit from, Type to) : where Type extends/inherits from Unit
    {
        // do the conversion
        return the instance of Type to;
    }
}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: `Convert<T>(T from, T to) where T : Unit` would probably be the appropriate solution.

Comment: vcsjones - would you mean Convert<T>(EngineeringUnit from, T to) where T : Unit?  You would need to pass an instance of T - i.e. a new Meter as second parameter - ideally you don't want the caller to instantiate the return type.  You would just want to say, here is a Inch instance, give me the Meter equivalent.

Comment: Unless there is a viable generics solution for this guys.  I've looked and looked but not seen anything that would fit.  Feel free to share any info I might have missed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the units are all known ahead of time you could use an [implicit conversion operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85w54y0a%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
public class Metre : Unit 
{
    public Metre() : base("Metre")
    {
    }

    public static implicit operator Inch(Metre m)  
    { 
        return new Inch(39.37 * m.Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes - and you have to update the individual classes if you want to add a new unit, not saying it's pretty either ;-)

Comment: Yes, there will be lots of units.  I put 2 on example for discussion, but kind of like the example.

Comment: A "workaround" could be that all units are convertible to meter, and meter would be convertible to all other units - kludgy but could use that in the converter class to get around the N*N conversions.